# Android Studio Failing to Load

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Android Studio Rendering Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXExl.jpg)

When I open android studio on my PC. This is the error that greets me at the beginning. How do I fix this eror?

Comment: What error are you seeing? You are going to need to give a lot more detail than this if you want an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.

You must do these 3 things:

Step 1: Delete '.AndroidStudio2.2' from "C:\Users\Your_PC_Account\"

Step 2: Start Android studio again.(If Android studio Downloading package don't stop it.)

Step 3: Create a new project.(Waiting for prepare new project)

Or install Android studio again.